# Javascript Create JSON Hash Array for jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am desperately trying to manually create a JSON-style array in Javascript to send over the network via jQuery's AJAX method.

```
var fieldsobj = {fields:[]}
$(".fact_field", fact).each(function(index, field){
    var index  = $(field).attr("data-index");
    var name  = $(".fact_field_label", field).text().trim();
    var value  = $(".fact_field_value", field).text().trim();
    fieldsobj["fields"].push({index:index, name:name, value:value});
});
//...
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: url,
    data: fieldsobj,
    success: function(data){...
    },
    complete: function(){...
    }
});
```

What I want is the following:

```
{fields => [{index:0, name:1, value:2},{...},{...}]}
```

What I get is this:

```
 {"fields"=>{"0"=>{...}, "1"=>{..}, "2"=>{...}, "3"=>{...}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you pass an object as the `data` property, jQuery will pass it as url-encoded form parameters (e.g. `foo=bar&moo=too`) in the body. I think what you want is to pass JSON through the body.

Grab the `json2.js` [written by uncle Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and use `JSON.stringify` (that library provides the functionality for browsers that still don't support it):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(fieldsobj),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){...
    },
    complete: function(){...
    }
});
```

And don't forget to set the `contentType` property! On the PHP side, you can use `json_decode` to decode the raw body content:

```
$fieldsobj = json_decode(@file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Great! I tried JSON.stringify before but I forgot about the content type.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps.

```
<ul>
    <li id="p1" data-age="40">John</li>
    <li id="p2" data-age="28">Jack</li>
    <li id="p3" data-age="50">Nash</li>
</ul>

<script>
var a = [];
$("li").each(function(i){
    var o = {};
    o.id = $(this).attr("id");
    o.age = $(this).attr("data-age");
    o.name = $(this).text();
    a.push(o);
});
console.log(a);
//var a = [{id:"p1",age:40, name:"John"},{id:"p2",age:28, name:"Jack"},{id:"p3",age:50, name:"Nash"}];
</script>
```